# drawable xml file in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

Cannot resolve symbol '@android:color/white'

Answer (score 0):

You can give color manually like

```
"#ffffff"
```

or create color in colors file like

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

then use like

```
@color/white
```

Comment: tried not working